# Android studio is not able to find cmake binary

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I have installed cmake in android studio and I have added the binaries in PATH variable.

[image]

[image]

But android studio keeps showing the error "Please make sure the folder with the CMake binary is added to the PATH environment variable." Restart doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps

1. **Uninstall** the CMake tool from **Android SDK** -> **SDK Tools** -> **CMake**.
2. **Reinstall** CMake to let your Android Studio overwrite your environment path.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using newer version of CMake than is supported by Android Studio.

Android Studio 3.3 supports CMake 3.10.2. If you create new project and try to open in Android Studio 3.2, you will get this error too.